# Databricks Type 2 / SLCD Updates via Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake

I have many times implemented slowly changing dimensions on DWH's in batch whereby a set of changes greater than 1, for a given business key, can be processed. No sweat.

Using following:

- Spark non-Structured Streaming Programs
- ETL tools
- PL/SQL

However, using Structured Streaming this is not possible as far as I can see due to multi-step nature and the limitations that prevail with Spark Structured Streaming.

Or is this possible? If so, please advise if there is a method?

Comment: Do you need SCD type 2 just for compliance, or for what purpose?

Comment: Kimball dwh approach i am used to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but you need to have some code to implement it. From your update dataframe you need to create a union of:

1. updates themselves, that will have a full merge key - they will match you'll set `current = false` and `end_date = date_of_new_record`
2. a result of inner join with the target table, but setting the merge key(s) to NULL, so they will not match & will be inserted as new rows with `current = true` and `end_date = null`

Code is from official [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-update.html#slowly-changing-data-scd-type-2-operation-into-delta-tables) (and [notebook](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/merge-in-scd-type-2.html)):

```sql
-- These rows will either UPDATE the current addresses of existing 
-- customers or INSERT the new addresses of new customers

SELECT updates.customerId as mergeKey, updates.* FROM updates

UNION ALL
 
-- These rows will INSERT new addresses of existing customers 
-- Setting the mergeKey to NULL forces these rows 
— to NOT MATCH and be INSERTed.

SELECT NULL as mergeKey, updates.*
FROM updates JOIN customers
ON updates.customerid = customers.customerid 
WHERE customers.current = true 
  AND updates.address <> customers.address
```

And then this resulting dataframe is used in MERGE statement that is called from the `.foreachBatch`

Comment: What if the business key has many type 2 updates in the same run? E.g. triiger.once. I am  going to try this tomorrow.

Comment: it requires slightly different code, but approach is the same - you need to have one record with the business key in the first part of union, so you can set `current = false`, and then in the second part have only records to insert, but already with `current` filled in based on the rank

Comment: Indeed i see. Will be looking and trying soon.

Comment: I note the sd & ed overlap, you should that that fixed

Comment: You mean in notebook?

Comment: Yep, bad practice.

Comment: I’ll communicate to docs team

Comment: Did you manage to test this successfully? I have the exact same scenario, but I cannot apply window (lag, lead) functions to a stream dataframe...